# Knockout: 2 nested foreach not working correctly in IE with the $data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js 2.1.0 and jQuery 1.8.
I have 2 nested foreach, this working well in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE (tested in 8 and 9).
In IE, the $data in the second nested foreach still corresponding to the parent foreach.

This is my view:

```
<!-- ko foreach: dropdowns -->
    <select>
        <option data-bind="text: title, value: title"></option>
        <!-- ko foreach: values -->
            <option data-bind="text: $data, value: $data"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And the JavaScript:​

```
var viewModel = {
    dropdowns: [
        {
            title: "Dropdown 1",
            values: ["value 1.1", "value 1.2", "value 1.3"]
        },
            {
            title: "Dropdown 2",
            values: ["value 2.1", "value 2.2", "value 2.3"]
        },
        {
            title: "Dropdown 3",
            values: ["value 3.1", "value 3.2", "value 3.3"]
        }
    ]
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I made a jsfiddle to test the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ebDt/

Is it a bug or I made something wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: IE strips comments inside `select` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE strips comments inside select tags.  For your scenario, you might want to consider using `optionsCaption` with the `options` binding.  It would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2ebDt/1/

```
<!-- ko foreach: dropdowns -->
    <select data-bind="options: values, optionsCaption: title">
    </select>
<!-- /ko -->​
```

The only difference is that the caption does not have a `value` set to the `title`.

Comment: Thanks! Small but important detail!

Answer (score 0):

This is where my [`repeat`](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding is useful. Here is your example using `repeat`: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/2ebDt/2/